# How to solve the complex line integral $\int_C \overline{z}^2 dz + z^2 d\overline{z}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, line-integrals

I'm reviewing complex analysis for the upcoming GRE. The following question is Problem 4.42 from *Schaum's Outline of Complex Variables*.

> Evaluate $\int_C \overline{z}^2 dz + z^2 d\overline{z}$ along the curve $C$ defined by $z^2 + 2z\overline{z} + \overline{z}^2 = (2-2i)z + (2+2i)\overline{z}$ from the point $z = 1$ to $z = 2+2i$.

The constraint simplifies to $y= x^2 -x$, and using the substitution $dz = dx+ i\ dy$ and $d\overline{z}=dx-i\ dy$, the integrand can also be simplified to:
$$ \int_C x^2 dx + (2xy +iy^2) dy $$

Of course, I can just plug in $y=x^2 - x$ and integrate the resultant polynomial equation term by term, but is there an easier way to do this question? I think there might be some symmetry that I can exploit, judging by the funky nature of $\overline{z}^2 dz + z^2 d\overline{z}$, but I'm not familiar enough with complex analysis to see what it might be.

Comment: not sure you got the integrand right - this looks like an application of Green's theorem btw

Comment: How would Green's theorem help if the path is not a closed loop?

Comment: assuming the integral on the closed-loop would be zero (!), it would allow to change the path of integration to something nice like the straight line or segments parallel to the axis- note that the form to integrate is $2\Re (z^2 d\bar z) =2(x^2-y^2)dx+4xydy$

Comment: Thank you. Yes, my integrand was wrong. I got the answer in the end.